# Why we may not know the value of the label when we encountered an instruction in assembly?

Tags: assembly, label, operation

Why we may not know the value of the label when we encountered an instruction in assembly?

For example, I read that in this code, the value of the label `LOOP` would not be known.
Why is this?

```
MAIN: 
  mov r5[r2],LENGTH
  add r2,STR
LOOP: 
  jmp END
  prn #-5
  sub r1, r4
  inc K
  mov r7[r6],r3
  bne LOOP
END: 
  stop
STR: .string “abcdef”
LENGTH: .data 6,-9,15
K: .data 22
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In what context did you "read" this? Did it imply that during a pass in the assembler that at the time it encounters the `LOOP:` label that it may not know the address of `end` yet?

Comment: It implied during the first pass in the assembler, the value of LOOP would not be known. It didn't really provide much information about the label END, so I am not sure @Frank C

Comment: Depending on your environment, the actual address may be determined later by the linker or even the loader. Note that you might only need a relative address and the assembler does know that.

Comment: Thank you very much. I still don't understand the reason behind this. I don't understand why the address of the other labels would indeed be determined, and yet the address of loop would not be? @Jester

Comment: What instruction set is this?

Comment: Nobody claimed the others are known ;) In fact if `LOOP` isn't then nothing that follows can be.

Comment: Thank you :) 
 They did claim that in the book though.
@Jester

Answer (score 3):

It is unclear what you are asking but...

Think about writing the assembler yourself.  As you parse through these instructions (what instruction set is this please provide a tag) you run across labels, you ideally go from top to bottom or beginning of the ascii file to the end.

The first pass on the file the labels that are defined before being used are MAIN and LOOP.  Then ones used then defined are LENGTH, STR, END and K.

Depending on the instruction set here the LENGTH and STR labels may be fine there might be only one possible instruction and the value/address of those labels doesnt matter, but lets say that the jump here has a near and far flavor which the assembly language uses the same syntax for.  The assembler cannot tell until it sees where END is and how far away whether or not it can encode ideally as a near, pc-relative jump or if it has to do a far possibly absolute address encoding, and that is fine in the long run but as they say multiple passes are required in some form (either literally across the file again or across internal structures).

LENGTH, STR, and K could possibly be pc relative as well vs a far version depending on the instruction set and the distance from LENGTH and STR to their label can vary by the encoding of the jump END.  The encoding of jump END might vary if the inc K encoding can vary.

My guess is that your question has to do with what instructions can we completely encode and know the size of and is the jmp END at the LOOP label one of those and that likely implies that there is a near and far jump in this instruction set and you cant determine the encoding until you have made at least one more pass and determine if END is local or global and how far away it is.

EDIT

So if I were to make up an instruction set, byte sized opcodes, variable length instructions.  Lets say that a two register and one memory operand mov is four bytes one byte of opcode, the second byte contains the information about the two registers and the next two bytes are the absolute address of the memory item (assume a 16 bit address space).  Lets also assume that in my fantasy instruction set the add register plus memory operand is also four bytes one byte of opcode, one byte to describe the register and two bytes of absolute address.  In that case assuming MAIN is known for some reason (all programs start at zero or there is a .org directive before main not shown here, etc.  Then with that mov and that add being fixed in length we can certainly say on the first pass that we know what the address of LOOP is.

But lets change it up. lets say that both the add and the mov have more than one encoding.  One opcode means two registers and a relative memory operand, a one byte relative memory operand, so take the address of the mov and you can go forward up to 127 bytes and backward up to 128 to find the memory operand, a three byte encoding, there also exists the absolute encoding four bytes.  Same deal for the add a three byte version/opcode that uses a pc relative address, and one that is four byte with an absolute.  So if we know the address of MAIN for whatever reason the address of LOOP can be MAIN + 6, or 7 or 8 bytes depending on how the mov and add turn out.  The assembler looks at one line at a time so the first line it sees a label called LENGTH but doesnt have any idea if it is local or global and if local how far away it is, is it within 127 bytes?  Likewise for the add with STR, it cannot determine in the first pass if it can take the shortcut and use a relative address or if it is forced to the longer absolute address.  So in that case the address of LOOP cannot be determined on the first pass.

So the instruction set, the machine code first and foremost determines these things then the author of the assembly language (assembly language is generally dictated by the assembler, the program that parses it and no reason to assume that for the same instruction set/machine code all assemblers use the same syntax.  one might have rjmp for relative and ajmp for absolute, another might just have jmp and the assembler tries to figure out relative vs absolute through multiple passes saving the programmer from having to change their code from rjmp to ajmp if the rjmp doesnt work out) determines what the syntax is and if it is vague or crystal clear.  Ideally assembly language has a one to one relation ship with machine code, but the reality is quite often you have pseudo instructions or mnemonics that resolve to different possible instructions.

EDIT2

you really have to be more clear what you dont understand.  Lets take the x86 instruction set I showed you.  There is a jmp rel8 which means jump relative to the current instruction using an 8 bit offset, in this case that means forward 127 bytes or backward 128.

You do understand what the assembler does yes?  It converts ascii assembly language into machine code, to understand these comments in these references you have to understand machine code, it is not hard it is documented right next to the assembly language.

So I use nasm to assemble these instructions.

```
org 100h
jmp over
nop
nop
nop
nop
over:
jmp over

nasm -o so.bin so.s
hexdump -C so.bin
00000000  eb 04 90 90 90 90 eb fe                           |........|
00000008
```

Looking at the jump instruction for x86, the relative 8 opcode is 0xEB and then the next byte is the relative offset.  We can see that they have encoded the first jump as 0xEB 0x04 so jump forward four.  Generally when an instruction is interpreted the program counter used is the value after reading in the instructions so even if 0xEB were at address 0x100 then 0x04 would be at address 0x101.  The four nops at 0x102, 0x103, 0x104, 0x105 (0x90 is a nop) so the over labe is at 0x106.  0x106 - 0x04 is 0x102, which is where the pc would be after reading the two byte instruction 0xEB 0x04, now the processor can say, okay I take the current PC (0x102) sign extend and add 0x04 which sign extends to 0x000...004 and the result is 0x106.  jump to 106.

And here is the key, the syntax for a jump relative 8 and a jump relative 16 and a jump relative 32 are the same you cannot tell by looking at the line with a label.  The assembler parses the source one line at a time

```
org 100h
```

Okay know what to do what that, means the programmer wants the program to start at address 0x100, so the next instruction will have the address 0x100.

```
jmp over
```

Okay there are at least three possible different instructions we can use here, jmp rel8 which is two bytes, jmp rel16 which is three and jmp rel32 which is five.  Because I have not seen the label over yet I cannot encode this instruction I am going to have to come back to it.

```
nop
```

I know what to do with that, encode 0x90...next

and it repeats through the nop lines.

Finally it sees this line

```
over:
```

Okay I can remember now where the over label is relative to the nops and such.  then the last line

```
jmp over
```

I have seen the over lable for this one, I can encode this one because I know where it is.  A two byte will work because I can do a jump -2 (0xFE is a negative 2)  A two byte instruction 0xEB 0xFE which moves the pc forward two and then jump back to to get to this label/instruction.

So I have completed the first pass

```
0x100: jmp over
is it 2 bytes, 3 bytes or 5?
??+0: 0x90 nop
??+1: 0x90 nop
??+2: 0x90 nop
??+3: 0x90 nop
??+4: over:
??+4: 0xEB 0xFE jmp over
??+6:
```

So lets make another pass.  We can work backward from the label over.  There are four instructions that we have completely resolved, a grand total of four bytes, so that is within an relative 8 jump so the first jmp over can be encoded as jmp rel8, which is two bytes so we can completely resolve our unknown labels from the first pass:

```
0x100:0xEB 0x04 jmp over
0x102: 0x90 nop
0x103: 0x90 nop
0x104: 0x90 nop
0x105: 0x90 nop
0x106: over:
0x106: 0xEB 0xFE jmp over
0x108:
```

So on the first pass it was not possible to determine the address of the label over because the first instruction jmp over could not be encoded and could have resulted in different length answers depending on where that label ended up.  On the second pass we were able to resolve how far away over was and what instruction encoding we could use.

Now if I put a ton of nops in between the first jmp over and the over label.  More than 127 nops.  The raw binary for mine becomes

```
00000000  e9 c9 00 90 90 90 90 90  90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90  |................|
00000010  90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90  90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90  |................|
*
000000c0  90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90  90 90 90 90 eb fe        |..............|
000000ce
```

0xE9 is the jmp rel16 opcode so this is a three byte instruction 0xE9, 0xC9 0x00  basically jump forward 0x00C9(+3) bytes from the jmp over instruction at address 0x100.  That is 201 bytes and that looks like how many nops I actually added.  So this demonstrates that the assembler upon parsing the first jump over cannot determine if it is a 2 byte or 3 byte or 5 byte instruction until it finds the label.  Using the terms of that other page the label is "below" the jump, in this case on line 2 I have the jmp over with the over label and on line 204 is the label so looking at the code the destination is below the jump to that destination on the page.

I dont know how to make this any more clear, some assembly language instructions refer to encodings  that can be different lengths and the answer to which encoding might not be determined until the label is resolved if the label is a forward reference.

Take the 8086 jmp rel8 and rel16 encodings the nop encoding label syntax and the org directive and write your own assembler repeat what I did above, put the over label a few nops away and then put the over label a couple hundred away, determine programmatically which instruction encoding to use.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation.  So does it mean that the value of labels that are used,after being defined, would not be known at the end of the first pass? I think I don't understand why the value of LOOP (it's address) would not be known at the end of the first pass. @old_timer

Comment: If you dont understand the answer or it has not resolved your question the why check this as the answer?

Comment: Well, I found this the most helpful answer around here, and it indeed helped me, though not entirely. Besides, I was just trying to express my gratitude. There's no need to say more, I unmarked it.
Anyway, suppose LOOP is of fixed size, then, I still don't understand, why wouldn't LOOP be known?
Thanks @old_timer

Comment: Tell me what the instruction set is so I can further explain it.

Comment: also wait more than an hour for answers to come in, give it a day or two for example even if there is a very strong answer to your question.

Comment: Got it, I will. As I understand it, this is the instruction set:
mov, cmp, add, sub, not, clr, lea, inc, dec, jmp, bne, red, prn, jsr, rts, stop.
Thanks @old_timer

Comment: not helping yet, I see that as a 20465 class? do you have a web page for the class that defines the instruction set (and in particular the machine code per instruction)?

Comment: Thank you.I don't have a web page for that, however, I do have a book containing that info. They say the first word in each instruction is constructed like so:
3 unused bits that are always 111,
2 bits for group (specifying the number of operands),
4 bits for the opcode,
2 bits for the addressing mode of the source operand (each addressing mode has a number that corresponds to it),
2 bits for the addressing mode of the destination operand,
2 bits for the ERA  filed,so the machine code corresponding the first word of the instruction mov r3[r2],LENGTH is
111-10-0000-10-01-00
 @old_timer

Comment: My question is really why are there times in which the encoding cannot be determined during the first pass? Thanks @old_timer

Comment: Because some assembly language are vague and there may be more than one encoding and the lengths of those encodings may vary depending on how far away the address of the label is.  a relative jump vs an absolute jump for example.  but you have a lot of instructions there with forward referenced items and without knowing the possible encodings for those mnemonics cant truly answer, can use examples of other instruction sets.

Comment: Thank you very much old_timer. I guess even examples of other instruction sets would be helpful :)

Comment: http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_147.html  the jmp instruction in x86 is an easy one to see that there are many different encodings with different overall number of bytes for each, and depending on the rest of the syntax, for example a relative 8 vs relative 16 might be written using labels and the assembler determines which form it is to take once it resolves the distance to the label.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and for the quick response. I really appreciate it.I still don't get it, but I have another, different example of what I don't understand Here,http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/324587/write-an-assembler-in-c-why-writing-a-machine-code-translator-for-a-low-level There's this comment that states this:
".... readily because we may not know the value of .... This happens if the label used by that jump instruction appear below that jump instruction...."I don't understand this comment. Why we many not know the value of label?
Thank you again.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind and detailed explanation.
 I really appreciate it!!!! @old_timer

Comment: Pay it forward...look around help someone out with something you know that they dont...